# Masking A Postprocess Unreal Engine 4.10

Tags: blur, unreal-engine4

I was able to make a full screen blur with the depth of field post process which I want to use for the background both my pause menus and my in game HUD. The issue is that when I want to use it for my in game UI it needs to only be rendered under the HUD and not the entire screen. Is there any way the I can mask the post process to a UMG widget for simplicity?

The other solution that I thought of was to create a material and mask it off in the material. The problem is that PostProcessInput0 already has the blur applied and I can't use the SceneColor any more, so I don't have a way to get the original texture without the blur. Is there any way to do this?

Cheers.